# cordova update device from another device

Tags: cordova, notifications, synchronization, push

when we make a change on our cordova app, we want to alert other (selected!) devices of that change.  I'd like it to happen in near real time.  A delay of a few seconds or up to a minute even is OK.  The devices are tablets and do not have phone but do have wifi and internet connections.

What sort of technology/framework should our dev team be using for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push).

This super-man **reliable** plugin offers support to receive and handle native push notifications with a single unified API.

It sends notifications in **realtime** (2-5 secs) if the devices are connected properly to the internet. The plugin also covers [foreground](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#push-message-arrives-with-app-in-foreground) and [background](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#background-notifications) scenarios. Take a look at its [platform support](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PLATFORM_SUPPORT.md#supported-platforms) before go ahead with this.

There are options for sending notifications to selected devices, to a set of devices registered to a topic, or to all the devices subscribed.

So whenever you make changes in your app, you can notify the devices using your app accordingly.